# PropertyGrid - Show properties of a specific Interface, not all properties

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, propertygrid

I am currently facing an (IMHO) strange behavior of the `PropertyGrid`:

I have an interface (`ITest`) that defines some properties. This interface will be implemented by a `Component` or a `Panel` (`TestImpl`). The other part is a `Component` (`TestComponent`) that has a public property of the interface type. A default implementation will be assigend to that property and it could be changed by the user to a more specific implementation. If I add this `TestComponent` to a `Form`, I would expect, that by expanding the public-interface-property, only the properties declared in the interface will be visible - instead all properties of the `Panel` or `Component` are visible...

```
public interface ITest
{
    string AAAAA { get; set; }
}

public class TestImpl: Panel, ITest
{
    public string AAAAA { get; set; }
}

public class TestComponent : Component
{
    [TypeConverter(typeof(ExpandableObjectConverter))]
    public ITest Obj { get; set; }
    public TestComponent()
    {
        Obj = new TestImpl();
    }
}

// To reproduce create a simple Form, add a PropertyGrid, create and assign the TestComponent
public partial class Form4 : Form
{
    public Form4()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var comp = new TestComponent();
        comp.Obj.AAAAA = "Some Text";

        propertyGrid1.SelectedObject = comp;
    }
}
```

Is there a way to show only the interface-properties?

Comment: `PropertyGrid` control shows all public properties of the object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PropertyGrid` by default shows display name of all public properties of your control which are browsable. It uses `TypeDescriptor` of your object to ask about its metadata including its browsable properties and their display names.

To customize this behavior you need to register a new `TypeDescriptionProvider` for your object.

**Example**

In the following example, I've created a  `MyPanel` control which derives from `Panel` and implements `IMyInterface`. Then I created a custom `MyTypeDescriptionProvider<T>` and set `MyTypeDescriptionProvider<IMyInterface>` as `TypeDescriptionProvider` of my control.

This way, when you set an instance of `MyPanel` as `SelectedObject` of the `PropertyGrid`, only properties of `IMyInterface` will be shown in `PropertyGrid`.

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public interface IMyInterface
{
    string MyProperty1 { get; set; }
    string MyProperty2 { get; set; }
}

public class MyTypeDescriptionProvider<T> : TypeDescriptionProvider
{
    public MyTypeDescriptionProvider() : base(TypeDescriptor.GetProvider(typeof(T))) { }

    public override ICustomTypeDescriptor GetTypeDescriptor(Type objectType,
        object instance)
    {
        return base.GetTypeDescriptor(typeof(T), instance);
    }
}

[TypeDescriptionProvider(typeof(MyTypeDescriptionProvider<IMyInterface>))]
public class MyPanel : Panel, IMyInterface
{
    public string MyProperty1 { get; set; }
    public string MyProperty2 { get; set; }
}
```

**Note:** As an important note, keep in mind that such functionality is not useful for design-time at all. Because at design time, you need to show properties of the control in `PropertyGrid` in designer and you need to let the designer knows about those properties to be able to serialize values for them.

Comment: Your answer solves my problem, but created another one. I've updated my question. Is there a way to define the behavior for each property-declaration instead of the type-defintion of the interface implementation?

Comment: @Michael To group properties, you should use `[Category]` attribute.

Comment: By the way, I believe the current edit has made the question less readable. If for any reason you believe you need that exact behavior and `[Category]` attribute is not what you are looking for, then it would be great if you revert the edit and post a new question regarding to the exact requirement :)

Comment: Ok, removed to edited part of the question. Do I need the this behavior? No. But I think its much easier to edit the properties if you see only the relevant ones instead of digging through the hole property-set of a panel looking for those that are not part of panel. I'll post another question...

Comment: Great. The question is much better now!

Comment: @Michael I have some options for your question in my mind. So let me know if you posted your question ...

Comment: Seems like I can skip the new question thanks to your `Category` hint... I'll implement the interface in the main component, delegate the calls to the concrete instance and put the interface properties in their own category...

Comment: You're welcome, great. It's really a better decision :)